# Getting undefined nativeElement when using @viewchid with *ngIf condition

Tags: javascript, angular

Getting undefined nativeElement when using @viewchid with *ngIf condition

Error

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Comment: Share your code to help people help you. Share only the snippets relevant to the issue and format them well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
@ViewChild('myElement', { static: false }) myElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

Don't call it in the constructor, `ngAfterViewInit` is the first hook to have it defined.

Answer (score 0):

If your `*ngIf condition is dynamic you should probably use a setter.

```
  @ViewChild('myElement') set setMyElement(myElement: ElementRef) {

    if (myElement) {
      // Here you can access content.nativeElement etc.
    }

  }
```